# Firebase extreme delay in function execution

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

A firebase cloud function has been implemented to be triggered every time the value of *price* changes, the code is as follows:

```
export const orderListener = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userId}/Order/{orderId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const { userId, orderId } = context.params;
    const price = change.after.data().price;
    try {
      if (price !== 0) {
        const userDoc = await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection(`/users/${userId}/Personal information`)
          .doc("Personal Information")
          .get();
        const { fcmToken } = userDoc.data()!;

        functions.logger.log({
          userId,
          fcmToken,
          orderId,
          price,
        });
        //RETURN
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, {
          notification: {
            title: "Title of the message",
            body: `${orderId}'s price > 0`,
          },
        });
      } else {
        return null
      }
    } catch (e) {
      functions.logger.error(e.message);
      //RETURN
      return null
```

This code has been deployed in the firebase function, and I tried to test it by changing the value of price, and monitoring execution by looking at firebase console.

Expectation:

As soon as I change the value of price in my firestore database, it executes almost immediately (within 5s).

Result:

The function executes just fine and was logged on the firebase console, but there is a **50 minutes delay** in execution after I updated the price value (Function execution was only logged 50mins later). It was tested by someone else but does not seem to have this issue.

Question:

Any potential error contained within this code? Is it likely to be some error with the firebase setup, settings, etc...?

- Edit: Thanks to the contribution of Dharmaraj I have updated the above code with return statements. The problem however still persists.

Comment: I would try adding `return` before `await admin.messaging()`, and also `return null` in every catch block in case of error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it ok if you write a few lines of the code to show what you mean?

Comment: Try copying code from this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/323c36d80d18dc2fb5933654e6040946) I added the return statements and removed the redundant try-catch

Comment: Thank you. But this bit of the code gave an error message onUpdate(
    async (change, context) => { .... return ...} with Not all code paths return a value.

Comment: I just edited the Gist. Try now.

Comment: I tried the code ..., but the problem still seem to exist, has not logged on the console after waiting a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider two things here:

1 - Cold Start of functions. If a functions is update or hasen't been used for a while it will kind of "shut down" or "go to sleep". When it gets triggered again it has a "cold start" that takes a while. It kind of boots the function from the "sleep"

2 -  The loggs are not in real time. The loggs are not shown in realtime. They also have some lag and deppending if you are watching them on the Firebase Console or GCP console you may need to refresh them manually.

50 min is way to much for a cloud function. I belive that you maybe just haben't seen the log as you expected it. It also could be that you test device was offline while trying it and it synced later. Without more information of your code, device and how you tested it it's hard for us to tell what exactly it would be but the mentioned szenarios are the most likely ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I kept refreshing my screen on the firebase console for the first few minutes, but nothing appeared. I didn't use any device and just changed the value of price straight of firestore, and monitor execution on firebase console.

Comment: Also: it is `onUpdate` so a creation won't trigger it and try to add just a simple `return` on the end of your function trigger. Just to let the function know when you are done.